# OO Databases that Pass by reference?

Tags: mongodb, oop, database, nosql

I have played with MongoDB a little and wondered is there every going to be, or can there even be a database which passes by reference or pointer.

E.g. I have a single user instance which can be put into multiple other arrays, if you change it once in one place it changes in all arrays.

I understand that in a database you don't want your data flung all over the disk but might we ever see one?

Comment: Create a small sample that illustrates your problem and post it so we can see what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would venture to guess you are accidentally creating multiple references when using MongoDB. There seems to be little value in creating a Graph for the database in which none of the nodes are shared.

I have used [db4o](http://www.db4o.com/) and it will maintain a single instance of an object such that if you change it, then reference it from another Object the change will be "reflected." I put that in quotes because they should be the same object due to the way graphs work.